# Sending mail with input file and images

Tags: asp.net, html, image, email, file-upload

How do i send an email where the body is an html file that the user choses in the (Fileupload) and the html file has images?

i want to embed the images in the body.

Comment: Are the images referenced by image tags in the uploaded HTML? Because then you will need to user to upload those as well.

Comment: I was thinking to get the img myself from the src.
example: <img src="C:\...\pic.jpg" />

Comment: You cannot get the image from the `src`, as you cannot read the user's local drive. And presumably, the images don't exist on your server in a location your users know about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are asking how to include images in an email, try this page: http://www.systemnetmail.com/faq/4.4.aspx

Comment: Moreover, sometimes its better to use inline attachment instead of linked resource, because outlook web access(owa) don't display linked resources due to some reasons.

Comment: +1 Didn't know about the `Linked Resource` option on System.Net.Mail.

Answer (score 0):

The most general way to embed images in html is by converting the image bytes to base64 string and setting the `src` property of the img element to be the base64 string.

For example, you can construct HTML as follows:

```
<img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhDwAPAKECAAAAzMzM/////
wAAACwAAAAADwAPAAACIISPeQHsrZ5ModrLlN48CXF8m2iQ3YmmKqVlRtW4ML
wWACH+H09wdGltaXplZCBieSBVbGVhZCBTbWFydFNhdmVyIQAAOw=="
alt="Base64 encoded image" width="150" height="150"/>
```

You, of course, need to convert the image bytes to base64 encoding. Example:

```
string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
```

Comment: This method shows a gray box in hotmail, how do i disable the gray box.

Comment: @Wergenwol: That's most likely a hotmail setting. Most providers block images by default on HTML emails unless the user clicks some sort of link to allow the displaying of images.